# how to write a macro to add metadata to a function

Tags: clojure

Given the below function -

```
(defn ^:export hi [] (+ 2 3))
```

I would like to write a macro that does this -

```
(defex hi [] (+ 2 3))
```

The macro `defex` just adds the ^:export metadata in front of the function. How do I do that?

Edit - I checked the function on repl (meta hi) and it gives nil. So most probably I dont want to add metedata but define a function in the above manner.

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want the meta on the function itself, you want it on the var (or whatever clojurescript's equivalent of that is):

```
user> (defmacro defex [name & defn-args]
        `(defn ~(vary-meta name assoc :export true) ~@defn-args))
#'user/defex
user> (defex hi [] "hi")
#'user/hi
user> (meta #'hi)
{:arglists ([]), :ns #<Namespace user>, :name hi, :export true, :line 1, :file "NO_SOURCE_FILE"}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a basic template-macro that builds a function and uses def to save it in a var

```
user> (defmacro defex [name args & body] `(def ~name ^{:export true} (fn ~args  ~@body)))
#'user/defex
user> (defex hi [] (+ 2 3))
#'user/hi
user> (meta hi)
{:export true}
user>
```